# How to do both Data Augmentation and Cross Validation at the same time in NLP?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, nlp, cross-validation

I have read somewhere that you should not use **data augmentation on your validation set, and you should only use it on your training set.**

My problem is this:

I have a dataset which has less number of training samples and I want to use data augmentation.
I split the dataset into training and test set and use data augmentation on the training set. I then use StratifiedKfold on the training set, which returns me a train index and a test index, but if I use the X_train[test index] as my validation set, it has some augmented images and I don't want that.

Is there any way to do data augmentation on the training set and do cross-validation ?

Here is my code(I haven't done data augmentation but would love to get a way to separate out the test_index from the augmented training samples.):

```
kfold = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5,shuffle=True)
i=1
for train_index , test_index in kfold.split(X_train,y_train):

  dataset_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train[train_index],                                                        
  y_train.iloc[train_index])).shuffle(len(X_train[train_index]))
  dataset_train = dataset_train.batch(512,drop_remainder=True).repeat()
  dataset_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_train[test_index],                                                     
  y_train.iloc[test_index])).shuffle(len(X_train[test_index]))
  dataset_test = dataset_test.batch(32,drop_remainder=True).take(steps_per_epoch).repeat()

  model_1 = deep_neural()

  print('-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
  -------------------------------')
  print('\n')
  print(f'Training for fold {i} ...')
  print('Training on {} samples.........Validating on {} samples'.format(len(X_train[train_index]),
                                                                       len(X_train[test_index])))
  checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(get_model_name(i), 
                           monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, 
                           save_best_only=True, mode='min')

  history = model_1.fit(dataset_train,steps_per_epoch = len(X_train[train_index])//BATCH_SIZE,
                      epochs=4,validation_data=dataset_test,
                      validation_steps=1,callbacks=[csv_logger,checkpoint]) 

  scores = model_1.evaluate(X_test,y_test,verbose=0)
  pred_classes = model_1.predict(X_test).argmax(1)
  f1score = f1_score(y_test,pred_classes,average='macro') 

  print('\n')
  print(f'Score for fold {i}: {model_1.metrics_names[0]} of {scores[0]}; {model_1.metrics_names[1]} 
  of {scores[1]*100}; F1 Score of {f1score}%')
  print('\n')            
  acc_per_fold.append(scores[1] * 100)
  loss_per_fold.append(scores[0]) 
  f1score_per_fold.append(f1score)

  tf.keras.backend.clear_session()
  gc.collect()     
  del model_1
  i=i+1
```

Comment: This is not really a coding question, but rather a question about ML principles, [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) might be a better place to ask.

Comment: Same question asked [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/482787/how-to-do-data-augmentation-and-cross-validation-at-the-same-time)